# Dictionary-like structure with custom search behavior

Tags: c#, dictionary, customization

I'm looking for a data structure which can do search on a specific key. The key is an interval. Once a single value is passed to this structure it should find the correct interval (appropriate key) then this key may point to several other values.

I searched for some key to multiple values and found something like this:

```
Dictionary<double,LinkedList<T>>
```

But the key value here is a simple double and is not interval type. And if it was interval type, I must pass the interval as the key. However I need to search based on a single value and find the interval.

**In other word, can we have a dictionary-like structure with a custom search behavior?** (for example pass the search as an Func<,> parameter.)

Comment: with the "dictionary-like structure", I means something that map key to value but we don't pass the exact key to it to find the value. instead we pass something then the mapping happens and ...

Comment: you can try Dictionary<Tuple<double,double>,LinkedList<T>>

Comment: @RTRokzzz the interval may be continuous not discrete

Comment: :I think you need your own logic to first find the key from the given interval, then this key may be useful for further logic.

Comment: @RTRokzzz maybe you're right. but I wanted to know if anyone have a better Idea.

Comment: Consider adding information about types of intervals to your question. I believe that if intervals do not overlap you can get better than binary search for arbitrary ranges. If intervals can overlap you'd need to not only find list of intervals but provide way to chose "the best interval".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov fortunately intervals do not overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know an existing structure like this.  But there are a lot of ways to solve this problem yourself.  First thing that comes to mind is to write an extension method for dictionary, like this:

```
public static class DictionaryRangeExtensions
{
    public IEnumerable<T> FindValuesInRange(this Dictionary<double,T> dictionary, double lowerBound, double upperBound)
    {
         dictionary.Where(kvp=> kvp.Key > lowerBound && kvp.Key < uppoerBound).Select(kvp=>kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Idea. but what does the this keyword here means? "this Dictionary..."

Comment: I don't want to find every key that lies in a range. My keys are some ranges and I have a single value. so I need to find the proper key (range) based on that value. (ranges do not overlap)

Comment: That's how extension methods work.  it means you can use it like this: `var values = myDictionary.FindValuesInRange(2.3, 5.7);`

Comment: +0, while correct, answer shows linear search that is nowere near to performance you get from lookup in Dictionary by key...

Comment: I posted another answer since I totally misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so I have to do a interval range search then use a simple`Dictionary`. let me know if this is the only optimal solution.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad, either you can map value to key in Dictionary in constant time (giving combined O(1) ) or you can't and than you need to perform searhc which is O(log N) for number of intervals (unless you can exploit some information about your data to make it faster).

Answer (score 2):

If the desire is to have ranges as a key and lookup by value, I think this will work as a key:

```
public class Range
{
   public Range(double lower, double upper)
   {
       this.lower = lower;
       this.upper = upper;
   }

   public override Equals(object obj)
   {
       if(obj is double) return ((double)obj) > lower && ((double)obj) < upper;
       //sensibly complete this method
   }

   //also override GetHashcode, probably to use the hashcode of upper and lower
}
```

Comment: +1: works for searching for ranges and by value when value can be mapped to interval in constant time (i.e. 1.5 -> [0,2])

Answer (score 0):

For non-overlapping intervals if you can map value to search to the interval in constant time - @tallseth suggestion with interval as Key in normal dictionary.

If you have to search for interval that the value falls into - store interval as sorted array (which you can easliy do as intervals do not overlap and hence `<` is defined for each pair of intervals). Than you binary search to find interval value fall into. With interval you can either index Dictionary or have data to contain "interval" and use approppriate function to pick interval from the dat for sorting/hashing.